# Rails: display number of pending request, hide() if there is no number

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails App, I want to display the `number of Request`.

If there is no pending `Request`, it shows `<a>Request<\a>`.
If there is pending `Request`, it shouws its number, like `<a>Request(2)<\a>`.

Here is what I come up with

```
<%= link_to "Request (#{@pending_request_number if @pending_request_number > 0})", friendship_requests_friendships_path, class: 'pull-right' %>
```

But It can only show like `Request ()` when there is no pending `@requests`. And I also want to configure the `css class`, which would make this line of code even longer.

How can I do it?

Comment: I am not getting your story about `()`,, Can you edit to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always split it to make it simpler:

```
<% if @pending_request_number.present? %>
  <%= link_to "Request (#{@pending_request_number})", friendship_requests_friendships_path, class: 'pull-right ative-class'  %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Request", friendship_requests_friendships_path, class: 'pull-right'  %>
<% end %>
```

But when it gets too complicate, you should consider extracting it into Helpers. Don`t try doing everything in one line.